# Hide the search field on a page without code

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

Can I somehow hide the search field on a page(that searches in the whole site) without writing code? I already have a search field from my document library and that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that, but all those require editing master page or the specific page in question.

The easiest way is using CSS. For that edit the page and add new web part. Select "Script Editor" web part. You can find this under group named "Media and Content".

Then click on "EDIT SNIPPET" and paste following

```
<style>
#SearchBox
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Click Insert. Stop editing and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to add content editor web part or snippet web part and add the following code to hide it:

```
<style>
    #titleAreaBox #SearchBox {display: none !important;}
</style>
```

Hope this helps!